# Send gdb commands in qtcreator debugger

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am most familiar with the gdb command line and greatly prefer it to qtcreator's GUI debugger. The qtcreator documentation (https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debug-mode.html#directly-interacting-with-native-debuggers) says this:
"In Qt Creator, you can use the left pane of the Debugger Log view for that purpose. When you press Ctrl+Enter, the contents of the line under the text cursor are sent directly to the native debugger. Alternatively, you can use the line edit at the bottom of the view."

But when I look at the left pane of the "Debugger log view" I do not see a "line edit" at the bottom. I also don't understand what they mean by the "contents of the line under the text cursor". Please see attached image. Can anyone help?

I am running QT Creator 4.8.1
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see Debugger Log in your screenshot. I get it from *Window* menu, *Views* submenu, which has checkable item *Debugger Log*.

Tested under Windows, Qt Creator 4.9.0, MinGW Qt toolchain, a simple test project runing in Debug mode.

Here is a screenshot showing where to find it, and a little bit of what it should look like after doing *`print argc`* when stopped at first line of `main`:

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Comment: Yes, please attach screenshot, showing gdb command input - thanks!

Comment: @Tomasso First, start debugging. Then, interrupt the application ("pause" icon). Now you can select `Window->Views` in Creator's menu bar, and in the pop-up menu enable `Debugger Log`.